# JavaScript can we carry what should be inside then() into method with parameters and call it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, callback, vuex

How can I avoid repeating code in then() when I handle callback
It is vuex module for user login and registration

```
    login({ commit }, user) {
        return AuthService.login(user).then(
            user => {
                commit('loginSuccess', user);
                return Promise.resolve(user);
            },
            error => {
                commit('loginFailure');
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
    },
    register({ commit }, user) {
        return AuthService.register(user).then(
            response => {
                commit('registerSuccess');
                return Promise.resolve(response.data);
            },
            error => {
                commit('registerFailure');
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
    }
```

I would like to make a function with parameters someting like this it gets mutation names and handles promse

```
function handleCallback(strMutationName1,strMutationName2, response, error) {
    response => {
       commit(strMutationName1, response.data)
       return Promise.resolve(response.data);
    },
    error => {
       commit(strMutationName2);
       return Promise.reject(error)
    }
}
And call previous methods like this 
    login({ commit }, user) {
        return AuthService.login(user).then(
            handleCallback('loginSuccess','loginFailure', response, error)
        );
    },
    register({ commit }, user) {
        return AuthService.register(user).then(
            handleCallback('registerSuccess','registerFailure', response, error)
        );
    }
```

Comment: You are not repeating code. That's your business logic right there. Creating a layer of indirection will make the code harder fo read and to follow. As a side node there is no need to call Promise.resolve(user). Just returning user will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `then` has two parameters so you would need to create two functions:

```
function successCallback(commit, name) {
    return response => {
        commit(name, response)
        return Promise.resolve(response);
    };
}
function failureCallback(commit, name) {
    return error => {
        commit(name)
        return Promise.reject(error);
    };
}
```

Then call them like

```
login({ commit }, user) {
    return AuthService.login(user).then(successCallback(commit, 'loginSuccess'), failureCallback(commit, 'loginFailure'));
},
register({ commit }, user) {
    return AuthService.register(user).then(successCallback(commit, 'registerSuccess'), failureCallback(commit, 'registerFailure'));
}
```

To make a single helper, you should either wrap the whole `then` callback

```
function handle(commit, name, promise) {
    return promise.then(successCallback(commit, name+'Success'), failureCallback(commit, name+'Failure');
}
```

```
login({ commit }, user) {
    return handle(commit, 'login', AuthService.login(user));
},
register({ commit }, user) {
    return handle(commit, 'register', AuthService.register(user));
}
```

or use spread syntax in the call, and return a tuple from the helper:

```
function handleCallbacks(commit, name) {
    return [successCallback(commit, name+'Success'), failureCallback(commit, name+'Failure')];
}
```

```
login({ commit }, user) {
    return AuthService.login(user).then(...handleCallbacks(commit, 'login'));
},
register({ commit }, user) {
    return AuthService.register(user).then(...handleCallbacks(commit, 'register'));
}
```